# Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ObjectBuilder for .netstandard/.net core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, dependencies

Im moving my project from .Net Framework 4.5.7.1 and I've installed the `EnterpriseLibrary` from nuget (pretty much every variant). I have compile time errors with the namespace: `Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration.ObjectBuilder` with no alternative. the 
`Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Common.Configuration` works fine and resolves.

any solutions for ObjectBuilder for .net core?

Comment: Microsoft no longer maintains EntLib, so you won't get an official release with .NET Core support. Someone forked it and published on GitHub, https://github.com/Chavoshi/EnterpriseLibrary.NetCore

Comment: @LexLi I've downloaded/incorporated  that version into my project with now success as described above `I've installed the EnterpriseLibrary from nuget (pretty much every variant)`